# How to change the ng-zorro theme at runtime

Tags: angular, angular9, ng-zorro-antd

I did a lot of research, and couldn't find a way to generate the ng-zorro themes and change it on the runtime.

Finally, I could find a way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Demo:** https://ashotaleqs.github.io/ng-zorro-switch-theme/

1. At first you need to install `less-plugin-clean-css` dev dependency by command `npm i less -D less-plugin-clean-css -D`
2. Create `themes` folder in `assets` folder
3. Define `less-compiler.js`
   which contains:

```js
const less = require('less');
const LessPluginCleanCSS = require('less-plugin-clean-css');
const fs = require('fs');

// ng zorro defined styles
const basicStyles = `@import './node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.less';`;
// ng zorro compact theme variables
const compactThemeVars = require('ng-zorro-antd/compact-theme');
// ng zorro dark theme variables
const darkThemeVars = require('ng-zorro-antd/dark-theme');

less.render(`${basicStyles}`, {
  javascriptEnabled: true,
  plugins: [new LessPluginCleanCSS({ advanced: true })],
  modifyVars: {

    ...compactThemeVars,
    ...{
      // for the compact theme
      // you need to add your color variables here
      // you can find the full variables list here
      // https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/master/scripts/site/_site/doc/theme.less
      'primary-color': '#111521',
      'error-color': 'green'
    }
  }
}).then(data => {
  fs.writeFileSync(
    // output path for the theme style
    './src/assets/themes/compact.css',
    data.css
  )
}).catch(e => {
  // log the render error
  console.error(e);
});

less.render(`${basicStyles}`, {
  javascriptEnabled: true,
  plugins: [new LessPluginCleanCSS({ advanced: true })],
  modifyVars: {
    ...darkThemeVars,
    ...{
      // for the dark theme
      // you need to add your color variables here
      // you can find the full variables list here
      // https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/master/scripts/site/_site/doc/theme.less
      'primary-color': '#02cadb',
      'error-color': 'yellow'
    }
  }
}).then(data => {
  fs.writeFileSync(
    // output path for the theme style
    './src/assets/themes/dark.css',
    data.css
  )
}).catch(e => {
  // log the render error
  console.error(e);
});
```

here is the link of the full variables [less variables](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/master/scripts/site/_site/doc/theme.less)

4. Run `node ./less-compiler.js` in the terminal (this command should generate the `dark.css` and `compact.css` files in the `src/assets/themes` folder)
5. **(optional)** If you want to run `node ./less-compiler.js` every time when you build the project, you can 
   replace `"build": "ng build",` with `"build": "ng build && node ./less-compiler.js",` in `package.json` and after you can build your project by `npm run build` command.
6. add `<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-link" href="/assets/themes/compact.css">` into the `head` of your `index.html` file.
7. Define a function that helps you remove or add the link of the theme into the head. (In my case the function defined in the `app.component.ts` file)

```js
// ..........................
export class AppComponent {
  theme = '';
  constructor() {
      setInterval(() => {
         this.changeTheme()
      }, 2000);
  }

  changeTheme() {
    this.theme = this.theme === 'dark' ? '' : 'dark';
    const style = document.getElementById('theme-link') as HTMLLinkElement;
    if (this.theme === 'dark') {
      style.href = '/assets/themes/dark.css';
    } else {
      style.href = '/assets/themes/compact.css';
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this can help you easily organize the runtime theme switching.

and also here is the link of the simple project repository

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/AshotAleqs/ng-zorro-switch-theme)

Answer (score 1):

The easier way could be just to create two theme files e.g. `theme-default.less` and `theme-dark.less`. default theme imports default `ng-zorro` styles and the dark theme imports dark `ng-zorro` styles. include them both in the assets section of `angular.json`. You just need to scope the dark styles under some class or something for them to applied conditionally. like this:

`theme-default.less`:

```
@import '~ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.dark.less';
// default vars
@primary-color: #3f87f5;
```

`theme-dark.less`:

```
body.dark {
  @import '~ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.dark.less';
  // dark vars
  @primary-color: #3f87f5;
}
```

Now you just have to apply the `.dark` class to the `body` to change the theme to dark.

Comment: Hi @Sinandro, thanks for your answer, but I couldn't make it work on my side, can you please share a small example. This is a great way to doing multi-theming. I will accept this answer if this will work. Actually not sure, maybe I did something wrong, or I am using an older version of the library?